# App returns to the root page instead of keeping current page when clicking refresh button in flutter for web

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I run my flutter app on web browser. Then from the root screen (A) I navigate to screen B and click refresh button on browser. My app turn back to the screen A instead of my expectation is that the app should be still at screen B. Is there any way to archive my expectation? Thank to any help!

Comment: what navigation library are you using.

Comment: @AkashSinha I just use Navigator.push. What about your idea?

Comment: try giving  go_router a try. if you want to store user current URL. use localStorage or sessionStorage

Comment: yes, I will take a look at go_route package. Thanks for your suggestion! @AkashSinha

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using web to run your flutter app. the web browser will redirect you to the main or starting screen of you flutter app on hot reload and even on refresh in browser .

Comment: Yup that is the case but I think this should be 2 different cases, shouldn't it? Like a website, when you refresh at a page, for instance a detail page, you still stand at the detail page not the home page. I would like to archive this behavior. Any suggestions?

Comment: yes, there is a way to do it by making your home in material app dynamic. you have to make it dynamic and to do it you have to store the data of lastly used page in browser  in the form of cookies. like sharedpreference

Comment: I got your idea. It looks promising @rishabh